# Create GCE VM with internet connection via API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I can create a new VM from image via cloud console and get automatically an external IP and internet connection on that VM. But when doing so via the API (node.js) I don't get an external IP and no internet connection on that VM. My code:

```
 var vmName = 'testvm1';
 const [vm, operation] = await zone.createVM(vmName, { os: 'ubuntu' });
 zone.createVM('debian-http', {
            disks: [{
                boot: true,
                source: 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[project-id]/zones/us-central1-f/disks/debian-http'
            }],
            http: true,
            machineType: 'f1-micro'
        })
```

What parameters do I have to apply to get an external IP?

Comment: Was the issue resolved or still having any issue?

Comment: I resolved it, see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added:

```
const config = {
            machineType: 'n1-standard-1',
            maintenancePolicy: 'MIGRATE',
            http: true,
          ...
}
```

not it works